# Have an image only display on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an email that shows one image only when viewed on mobile and one image only when viewed on desktop on desktop.

I have gotten the desktop image to correctly disappear when viewed on mobile, but I am unsure how to get the same result for the reverse.

Any help would be appreciated.

The CSS I am using is as follows:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

 .img-max {
   width: 100% !important;
   max-width: 100% !important;
   height: auto !important;
 }

 .max-width {
   max-width: 100% !important;
 }

 .mobile-wrapper {
   width: 85% !important;
   max-width: 85% !important;
 }

 .mobile-padding {
   padding-left: 5% !important;
   padding-right: 5% !important;
 }

 /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
 .mobile-hide {
    display: none !important;
 }
 .mobile-show {
    display: block !important;
 }

}
```

And the HTML

```
<img class="mobile-show" border="0" height="50" src="images/logo.svg" style="display: block;" width="250">
<img class="mobile-hide" border="0" height="50" src="images/logo.svg" style="display: inline;" width="100">
```

Comment: Add you PC css above your media query so that the media query overwrites it when in mobile.

Comment: you are using `mobile-show` and `mobileShow`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to setup a second media screen:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

  /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
 .mobile-hide {
    display: none !important;
 }

}
```

Comment: I know all of you guys have solutions for this. But this one worked the best for me.

Answer (score 3):

**First of all add this meta tag for mobile deivce support if its missing like below.**

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

> Then using media queries you can achieve the thing you want.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.mobile-hide {
    display: none !important;
 }
 .mobile-show {
    display: block !important;
 }
}
.mobile-hide {
    display: block;
 }
 .mobile-show {
    display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.mobile-hide {
    display: none !important;
 }
 .mobile-show {
    display: block !important;
 }
}
.mobile-hide {
    display: block;
 }
 .mobile-show {
    display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to hide your mobile image always except in the mobile. So add a display:none to your image. Then your image will not appear no desktop and your CSS with medi will make it appear.

```
<img class="mobileShow" border="0" height="50" src="images/logo.svg" style="display: none;" width="250">
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
 .desk-hide {
    display: none !important;
 }
 .desk-show {
    display: block !important;
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

 .img-max {
   width: 100% !important;
   max-width: 100% !important;
   height: auto !important;
 }

 .max-width {
   max-width: 100% !important;
 }

 .mobile-wrapper {
   width: 85% !important;
   max-width: 85% !important;
 }

 .mobile-padding {
   padding-left: 5% !important;
   padding-right: 5% !important;
 }

 /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
 .mobile-hide {
    display: none !important;
 }
 .mobile-show {
    display: block !important;
 }

}
```

```html
<img class="mobile-show desk-hide" border="0" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" style="display: block;">
<img class="mobile-hide desk-show" border="0" src="https://www.socialtalent.co/wp-content/uploads/blog-content/so-logo.png" style="display: inline;" />
```

You've created two classes for handling the mobile size behavior. Now, you have to do the same for desktop size. If you want this to work as intended, place the desktop size rules above the `@media`. So in the default screen size, the desktop rules are being applied, but when screen became less than 600px, it will apply the `@media` rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use picture tag which can use many image sources, example:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="images/logo-mobile.png" media="(max-width: 720px)">
    <img src="images/logo.png">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are tablets mobile in your opinion or do you just want mobile phones? With todays phones and tablets it's unreliable to trust a simple media query like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { }
```

Best way in my opinion is to use Javascript or PHP ( this PHP class is very interesting [github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) ) to detect what device is being used and then apply the right style.

Its light, reliable and gives you all the data over what devices do your users have and it's always handy to know not just the device but also resolution, pixel depth, etc. & have even different image files for different users.

Comment: Yes, that class is fine but the OP want this for styling the email, so PHP is not an option